# email uniqueness validation with subdomain scope in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I am using `devise` gem for registration un My rails 5 API
Now I have problem is that, I want to register same email address user if subdomain is different, So My step is

1) Update user index

```
add_index :users, [:email, :subdomain], unique: true
```

2) in user.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
validates :email, uniqueness: {:scope => :subdomain}
```

Now in console

- User.last

`#<User id: 111, email: "test@gmail.com", subdomain: "test">`

- Create new user with same email and different subdomain

`User.create!(email: "test@gmail.com", subdomain: "test1")`

Error

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE 
 "users"."email" = $1 AND "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND 
 "users"."subdomain" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["email", 
 "test@gmail.com"], ["subdomain", "test1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE 
 "users"."email" = $1 AND "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL LIMIT $2  
 [["email", "test@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure that index in DB so smart to check uniqueness with scope. In general you don't need to do any validations on DB layer. So try to remove validation on DB layer, it should help.

Comment: Are you sure `User.exist?(email: "test@gmail.com", subdomain: "test1")` return `false`

Comment: @AmitPatel yes its returning false

Comment: 2.4.0 :012 > User.exists?(:email => "test@gmail.com", :subdomain => "test1")
  User Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 AND "users"."subdomain" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["email", "test@gmail.com"], ["subdomain", "test1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => false

Comment: @nautgrad - what  are you talking about? Using a DB index safeguards against race conditions and is a very good idea if uniqueness is important. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations

Comment: @max Thx for article. Ye it's possible to create 'not unique' record if you rely only on rails validation. But you need to have true heavy-load to witness this record. In other hand you waste time to refresh indexes in table each time you are inserting record.

Comment: It's not a waste of time. A few ms of performance against data integrity...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `validatable`, add the following to your user model:

```
validates :email, presence: true
validates :subdomain, presence: true
validates :email, uniqueness: {:scope => :subdomain}

def email_required?
  false
end

def email_changed?
  false
end
```

Ref: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address

Comment: but this will remove email presence, I mean so now I can create user without email.

Comment: I want to create user with same email with different subdomain and both are compulsary.

Comment: add the validation yourself like I did now

Comment: You want to add  `validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: 'subdomain'` and a presence validation `validates :email, :subdomain, presence: true`

Comment: still same issue

Comment: I don't think this will work - see https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4767

Comment: @Pak this definitely used to work with the version I was using 3 years ago. Can't confirm if it still works with the latest devise version.